# get all entry points in a python library I use? (static analysis)

Tags: python, static-analysis

I'd like to examine a python project of mine for all 'apis' it's using of another module.

Precisely: I'm using internals of the mercurial python code, and I'd like to get a list of which code points I need to check where when updating the used version of mercurial.

I guess I'll need some form of static analysis. Nothing that's proof against malicious code, but better than just grep.

Comment: Ever felt the embarrassment when you ask a public question and fixed the very same problem yourself ages ago?

Last time I was up to the task, I wrote https://github.com/Pike/pygrep. I'll probably just use that again this time.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a test suite you could run those tests under a profiler and it will collect for you a handy list of all function calls that you can then sort/filter based on what module they were in (for example if they were in mercurial).  For example to run your program through cProfile which is included in most versions of Python just call

`$ python -m cProfile -o myprog.prof path/to/myprog.py [program arguments]`

You can run the tests through cProfile, or if you don't have tests you can just manually run it through some functional tests to pick up what mercurial API calls actually get used during normal usage.

This won't be as thorough as static analysis but it also might give you a clearer picture of what functions actually get called.  You can then use the [pstats module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-pstats) to analyze the results, or a graphical profile viewer like [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) or (shameless plug) [SnakeViz](http://jiffyclub.github.com/snakeviz/).